# Joining column into MySQL query as a delimited list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL that looks like so:

```
date      | name    | status
03-13-2014,Bob Jones,Pending
03-13-2014,George Manuel,Pending
03-13-2014,Tom Grables,Pending
03-13-2014,Frankie Avalon,Approved
03-13-2014,Robert Garcia,Approved
03-14-2014,John Doe,Pending
03-14-2014,John Die,Approved
03-14-2014,John Zoe,Approved
```

What I am trying to do is grab date, name and status for all rows that say approved. However, I am also wanting to join this query in such a way that each row I grab also has a semicolon delimited list containing the names of those whose status is pending and falls on the same day as an approved. Thus, the output of my query would look something like this:

```
03-13-2014,Frankie Avalon,Approved,Bob Jones;George Manuel;Tom Grables
03-13-2014,Robert Garcia,Approved,Bob Jones;George Manuel;Tom Grables
```

Notice that I grabbed the approved requests for 03-13-2014 and added the requests whose status is pending and whose date matches the approved request as a column. I've been messing around with the join statement, and done my Google homework, but have yet to find a way to do this.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT('name` SEPARATOR ',') as NameList
FROM
    `tablename`
GROUP BY
    `date`
```

Comment: `','` is the separator if none is specified

Comment: Yeah. I specify one out of habit.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
 select `date`,
         group_concat( (case when status = 'Approved' then name end) separator ';') as Approveds,
         group_concat( (case when status = 'Pending' then name end) separator ';') as Pendings
 from t
 group by `date`;
```

If you really do want pending *only* on dates where there are no approved, then you need an additional filter:

```
 select `date`,
         group_concat( (case when status = 'Approved' then name end) separator ';') as Approveds,
         group_concat( (case when status = 'Pending' then name end) separator ';') as Pendings
 from t
 group by `date`
 having `date` in (select `date` from t where status = 'Approved')
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I've been working at this for a few days now and within minutes my question has been answered. You guys are great, and I appreciate you showing me something new (group_concat).